How to set the first picture of every folder as its folder icon?
I'm new to programming so I don't know how to work this out!
I have plenty folders containing images. So working with them gets very tiresome thus i have to click and open each folder to see which is which. I know there is a mannual way of doing it but there are few thousand folders. So, doing it mannualy is impossible for me.
So, is there any script or any program which will set the first image of every folder to its folder icon and it will change the icon of all the folders of that directory.
I tired searching everywhere but couldn't find any solution! So, this is the last hope for me. If anyone can do this, please help me.
I'm currently using Win 8.1. TIA for the support.
Edit_1: The images in the folder are named sequentially like the first img is 1 and then 2 and so on(same in all folders). So I guess alphabetically the first image would do the work. hope this helps.

What is "first"? The first in alphabetical order, the first one which has been added to the folder?

That would be  the first which has been added to the folder

I don't know whether Windows keeps a historical record of what happened in a directory. AFIK, Windows stores the creation time of the directory, and of the files themselves, but if you create the file somewhere else and just move it into this directory, I don't think it will get a new timestamp, but not being a Windows guy, I don't know for sure. Hence, your question boils down to "How can I find the first file which as been added to a directory". I suggest that you rewrite the question in this way, I think it will be easier to understand and answer.

It can also be alphabetical order. the images have been named sequentially like the first img is 1 and next is 2 and so on. so i think it should not be a problem to you now. and thanks for the suggestion about the ques

Alphabetical is of course easier and depends on the collating sequence. You just have to make sure that your LC_COLL is set in the way you need, when you calculate the sorted list of names. I hope that you are away that in your naming scheme, picture 2 comes after picture 10?

One more point (since you are new on SO): You are looking for a solution using bash. This is fine, but on Windows, you better specify which bash implementation you are going to use (WSL, Cygwin, git-bash). Also you are expected to at least show your own attempts to solve the problem, so show the bash program you have written so far, so that we can see where you got stuck.

Yes, the sorting on each folder is in correct order. like if i have 20 images in a folder, the naming starts with 1 and ends with 20  and also it shows exactly as the number sequence follows. And for my own implementation part as I mentioned I just started learn programming. and i'm really on the basics. So, i can't do any implementation as I don't understand them yet. But i did had intention of creating my own solution but as far as I understood I'm way far from  making my own. but I have to deal with this problem almost everyday and it has become unbearable for me.

I hoped anyone would be kind enough to help me get out of this mess. I really didn't mean to create any commotion. If it hurts you in any way, I'm sorry.

This would then be not alphabetical order, but numerical order, and it means that the file names consist ONLY of numbers (and extension). If this is the case, this must be specified in the posting, not in a comment.

Basically, your question consists of two parts: (1) Find in a given directory the path of the first picture, (2) If you have a path to a picture, how to make a folder icon out of it. I strongly suggest to create two different posts for these questions, because they need different knowledge to be answered. You can get a better answer if you don't lump everything into a single question.

What surprises me is that you claim to have started to learn programming, and want to do this in bash. From this I conclude that you learn programming using bash, which is possible, but a bit unusual. Still, if you really want to go this way, I bet you will get more response (instead of downvotes) to show at least a general sketch of the bash program you have in mind here.


Determine the changes that happen to the folder.

When changing the icon, the path to the icon gets stored in a hidden desktop.ini file in the folder. I think it's the same when changing the thumbnail.
The folder gets marked "read-only" which tells Explorer to pay attention to the desktop.ini file.


Write a script that sets the icon for one folder – IIRC, Windows 8.1 already has PowerShell 5, which would be the easier option (rather than cmd.exe).

List the folder's contents using Get-ChildItem (aka dir) and take the first *.jpg item;
$first_item = (dir $folder\*.jpg)[0]
$first_item_path = $first_item.FullName

If some specific order is needed, dir ... | sort ... should work.

create a $folder\desktop.ini with the correct contents,
echo "whatever=$first_item_path" > $folder\desktop.ini


set the hidden attribute on $folder\desktop.ini,
$x = Get-Item -Force $folder\desktop.ini
$x.Attributes = $x.Attributes -bor [IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden


set the read-only attribute on $folder itself, so that Explorer would start looking for the desktop.ini file.



Extend the script to loop over subfolders in a specified folder.
Get-ChildItem -Directory $start_path | ForEach-Object ...



